# Wordpress API: How do I get post by category with vue js on laravel

Tags: php, json, wordpress, laravel, vue.js

I build a cms system using laravel and vue js in front end and wp rest api in backend. So I have news category as a post, I only want news category to appear in my page, how to do it because right now I get all post from all category ? is it possible, here is my vue js code to get all post

```
    <script>
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html'
export default {
    created(){
        axios.get('http://localhost/newlara/main/public/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=9')
        .then(response => {
            //console.log(response);
            this.posts = response.data
        })
    },
    data(){
        return{
            posts: []
        }
    },
     methods: {
        stripTags(html) {
            return sanitizeHtml(html, {
                allowedTags: []
            }).substring(0, html.indexOf('&hellip;'))
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: you want to load all your posts from backend and split them in frontend?

Comment: I want to load posts from category that I make with wordpress, I have news category. From my code now I can load all my post from wordpress backend

Answer (score 2):

You can get post from a particular category by

```
 http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/<id>
```

Have a look at the documentation here

https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/